# Disable certificate validation

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe2, x509certificate

I need to consume a WCF, but it has a certificate and I need to disable its authentication.
Does anyone know how can I do this in Delphi XE2?

I've already tried the codes below:

First attempt :

`Rio.HTTPWebNode.InvokeOptions:= [soIgnoreInvalidCerts,soAutoCheckAccessPointViaUDDI];`

Where Rio is a THTTPRIO.

Second attempt:

```
    class procedure ClasseTeste.OnBeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
      Data: Pointer);
    var
      SecurityFlags: DWord;
      SecurityFlagsLen: DWord;
      Request: HINTERNET;
      begin
      Request := Data;
      if soIgnoreInvalidCerts in Rio.HTTPWebNode.InvokeOptions then
      begin
        SecurityFlagsLen := SizeOf(SecurityFlags);
        InternetQueryOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
        Pointer(@SecurityFlags), SecurityFlagsLen);
        SecurityFlags := SecurityFlags or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID;
        InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
        Pointer(@SecurityFlags), SecurityFlagsLen);
      end;
    end;

rio.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost:= ClasseTeste.OnBeforePost;
```

I can do this using c#, with the code below:

```
channel = new ChannelFactory<WsMain.IWsInterface>("****");
                channel.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "*****";
                channel.Credentials.UserName.Password = "*****";
                channel.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

Comment: Should not it be disabled on the server side? I wonder if having a client able to disable certification is a safe behavior... :)

Comment: I agree with you, but in this case the service isn't ours. I know that it's possible to disable in C# and I want to do the same behavior in Delphi.

Comment: I don't really get the question here: is the certificate on the server somehow invalid(selfsigned etc.) or the server requires certificate authentication? I ask this because a server could have a certificate, but may not require certificate authentication - the cert could be used for SSL tasks only. Also please show us what error you are getting?

Comment: The server requires authentication.
The WS's owner told that I have to disable the authentication before access its metods, this is the only way that can make consume works.
Without remove certificate require, the response is a simple time out, while in C# (removing require) the return is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines after your request:

```
  SecurityFlags := SecurityFlags or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
  InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, Pointer(@SecurityFlags), SecurityFlagsLen);
```

Which would done:

```
procedure TForm1.RIO_OnBeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
  var
   SecurityFlags: DWord;
   SecurityFlagsLen: DWord;
   Request: HINTERNET;

begin
  Request := Data;

  SecurityFlagsLen := SizeOf(SecurityFlags);
  InternetQueryOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, Pointer(@SecurityFlags), SecurityFlagsLen);

  SecurityFlags := SecurityFlags or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;
  InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, Pointer(@SecurityFlags), SecurityFlagsLen);

  // It solved my problem
  SecurityFlags := SecurityFlags or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
  InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, Pointer(@SecurityFlags), SecurityFlagsLen);


end;
```